# C# Trying to keep data input in an array from multiple classes

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

Apologies for the weird wording in the title. I don't know the proper term for it.

I think I understand the issue, but I'm not sure what the fix is.

Basically I am trying to keep information in an array that is input by the user from every class that utilizes it.

Here is the class where the array object is pulled from:

```
    public class InitialNumberInput
    {
        private List<float> _inputList = new();

        public List<float> InputList
        {
            get { return _inputList; }
            set { _inputList = value; }
        }

        private float[] _inputListArray = Array.Empty<float>();

        public float[] InputListArray
        {
            get { return _inputListArray; }
            set { _inputListArray = value; }
        }
    }
```

I then initialize the array from this method into another one where the user inputs numbers.

```
    public class InputToArray
    {
        public static void ReadNumberInput()
        {
            InitialNumberInput obj = new();

            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                {
                    obj.InputListArray = obj.InputList.ToArray();

                    break;
                }

                float inputNumber = float.Parse(input);
                obj.InputList.Add(inputNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I iterate with a foreach loop every number in InputListArray in this specific method, I get every number that was input. That's fine and dandy. But when I call the object in another class, if I try to iterate the array again, it comes up as empty.

I believe this to be the case because when the object is being initialized in another class, its value is reset to the original value, which is nothing.

I thought that adding a readonly prefix to the array might be the solution, but it creates errors in the code. I played around with it but, at least with what I have written, I'm not sure what the solution to this might be. I did some digging for the past two hours on a solution, I think my lack of proper wording is making it so I can't find a proper solution for my issue.

Any help or clarity on my issue is appreciated. Additionally, please let me know if I am doing something inefficient or non-standard in my coding (I only recently learned about getters and setters, so if something is off, please let me know, always happy to learn)

Comment: You are creating a single instance of `InitialNumberInput` but you aren't keeping a reference to it anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to have the InputListArray be the same for each instance of InitialNumberInput, you should use static. The static modifier makes a property the same no matter what instance you are trying to retrieve the property from. If you made InputListArray static, like this:

```
public static float[] InputListArray
    {
        get { return _inputListArray; }
        set { _inputListArray = value; }
    }
```

you could then

```
   public class InputToArray
{
    public static void ReadNumberInput()
    {
        InitialNumberInput obj = new();

        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                InitialNumberInput.InputListArray = obj.InputList.ToArray();

                break;
            }

            float inputNumber = float.Parse(input);
            obj.InputList.Add(inputNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then access it from another class in the way you left it:

```
public class OtherClass {
    private void OtherMethod(){
        InitialNumberInput.InputListArray = //do some stuff here  
        //it will have the same value that you gave it before
    }
}
```

You also might have to make InputList static as well depending on what you are doing in the other class. You might want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static.